# Filter and sort based on derived properties in Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have Spring Boot web application based on Spring Data REST. Generally, I add interface which extends `JpaRepository`, `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` and `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`.

Spring Data REST will expose all query methods as [search resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.search-resource).
All is well and settled for persistent fields where Spring Data's web support nicely maps HTTP request params to persistent fields in entity:, e.g.

```
@Getter
@Entity
public class Person extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    // persistent fields
    @Embedded
    private PersonName name;

    @Embedded
    private PersonSurname surname;

    @Embedded
    private Age age;

    // derived field
    Status status() {
        return age.isGreaterThan(30) ? Status.MARRIED : Status.FREE;
    }

    public enum Status {
        MARRIED,
        FREE;
    }

}
```

Thanks to QueryDSL support, I can issue filter or sort requests and I can also combine multiple filters and sorts.

How can I filter and sort based on derived property, such as `Status` in `Person` class above?
and having it compatible with typical filtering and sorting capabilities, e.g. I could issue http://localhost:8080/people?name=Alice&status=MARRIED

Comment: Sory, you tried QueryDSL and it didn't work or what?...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't recognize derived fields.. so when I want to filter based on status: http://localhost:8080/people?status=MARRIED, it returns everything.. status is not saved in database as you can see in the example

Comment: I've created [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/querydsl-demo) - it works as expected. You can try: http://localhost:8080/persons?gender=MALE

Comment: @Cepr0 Sorry for delay.. The problem with your demo is that `gender` is database column, so it is persistent field. I'm looking for being able to filter on fields which are derived (based on the state of `Person` object) and they are not stored in database table

Comment: As I understand such approach is not supported by Hibernate or Spring. (And there isn't the problem with my demo :) )

Comment: Yeah, demo is nice :), but it doesn't show solution to my problem.. my current approach is to define @Query in repository, this gets exported as search resource.. problem with that is you can't combine it with querydsl based filtering

Comment: As it is said in the question linked as duplicate: Any kind of filter, in the end, becomes a where clause in a SQL statement. Therefore it is not possible to access information only available outside the database.

Comment: In the end I figured out how to do it thanks to `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`, `QueryDSL` custom bindings and forcing `QueryDSL` to generate path for derived field.. I can't post the answer as this question is marked as duplicate.. it is true that it has to be backed by where clause in database

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin could you add your `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` answer to the linked (duplicate) question, as I don't see that approach given as an answer there.